# async & multithreading in windows form

Tags: c#

I am retrieving data of about 100k rows from a database into a datagridview.This process takes up to 5-6 seconds.however during these seconds the user can't move the mouse or click any other button.how can I use aysnc/multithreading to achieve smooth user interface.

Comment: Make a new thread that does the work.

Comment: As multi threading always increases complexity and may be the source of many bugs hard to track: Is it worth it? Waiting 5-6 seconds seems not so much to me...

Comment: @Udontknow Clearly you don't have a lot of experience working with applications that freeze when they're doing work.  It's a horrible user experience.

Comment: @Udontknow I think it is almost always worth it.  Except in trivial unit tests, I always let the UI thread play conductor and event handler and pretty much nothing else.  And for a simple threading exercise, it literally takes only two or three extra lines of code to run it on a separate thread.

Comment: Agree with above.  Especially in C#, which has probably the best async support of any language, there's little excuse for not doing it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Look into the Task library and async, there's a whole section of C# for doing exactly this.

Basically you wind up with things like . . .

```
var records = await GetRecordsFromDatabase();
MyDataGridView.ItemSource = records;

private Task<IEnumerable<Record>> GetRecordsFromDatabase(){
    return Task.Run(() => {
          //do stuff the return IEnumerable<Records>
    });
}
```

Note that while you can use threads, Tasks are a much better option in C# for async support.

Edit - most databases should support some async operation.  In that case you'd likely have an async method to transform things from the database to the format you need.  You'd also likely want to follow the convention of marking your own method as async.  Something like . . . .

```
private async Task<IEnumerable<Record>> GetRecordsFromDatabaseAsync(){
    var dbRecords = await Database.GetRecordsAsync();

    //transform the database records and return them
}
```

And call it as above.

Comment: You should not be using `Task.Run` here; he's doing IO work, not CPU bound work, so the operation is already inherently asynchronous.

Comment: You're totally right.  However I'm curious - does that happen at the method level, or does that just assume that the database supports an async operation in the do stuff area?

Comment: It has nothing to do with what the database supports, it's all about the client you're using to connect to that database.  The interaction is, by its very nature, already asynchronous.  Some clients hide that asynchronously for you by blocking execution until the asynchronous operation finishes, some expose the operation in an asynchronous manor, and some expose both operations.

Comment: I mean the database client supporting async, not the database itself.

If the database client does not offer an async method, but instead blocks on read, then just declaring the method as Task<IEnumerable> is not going to do the job.  Instead a compiler warning will tell you that the operation will occur synchronously.  Since this will be on the UI thread, the OP would continue to have a problem.  My take anyways - if I'm incorrect there I'd love to see why.

Comment: Most database clients do actually support some form of asynchronous operation.  It's pretty unusual to find one that doesn't.

Comment: Oh sure.  I'll update the code to show that, as it is the most likely scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume you are doing all of this processor intensive work as a result of a button click.  Hopefully you already have the work in a separate method and are calling that method from the click event.  If you actually have all of your work inside the click event, move it out into its own method and call it from the click event handler.

Now that is still on a single thread.  I'll just address using a separate thread here, though you should look into tasks on your own as well.  To use a separate thread for the hard work, write 2 lines of code like this:

```
Thread t = new Thread(nameOfTimeConsumingMethod);
t.Start();
```

And that will do it.  If you need to write output to, say, textBox1, you cannot do so directly from the new thread (no cross thread calls).  But you can still write to that box easily enough indirectly like so.

```
BeginInvoke(new Action(()=>textBox1.text = "Hello world!"));
```

Comment: Thanks mate,il try this too